# Moved my codebehind files into App_Code and now Visual Studio can't find them

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, iis-8.5

I've written a simple webservice using ASP.NET and C#. Everything was working great on my local dev environment, but when I pushed it up to our staging server, it wouldn't run. After some trial and error, I was able to get the webservice running by putting the webservices's .asmx and the Global.asax's code-behind files in the App_Code directory.

But, when I made this change on my local dev server, I get errors from Visual Studio telling me it can't find the .cs files anywhere. I've tried updating the markup in each file to point to App_Code/Global.asax.cs (for example), but that doesn't help. Is there a way where I can update the path to the code behind files? I'm starting to think it may be easier for me to start the project over and make sure the code-behinds end up in App_Code properly, but that also seems a bit overkill.

I've Googled around but can't find anything conclusive, so it's likely I don't know how to ask the question. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web and the staging server is Windows Server 2012 running IIS8.5.

Thanks!

Comment: From your description it sounds like you deployed your source code to your webserver rather than just the DLLs and the markup. You shouldn't deploy the code behind files at all. Take them out of app_code and put them back where they were. Then use the visual studio publishing wizard to create a deployable set of file.

Comment: I used an "empty web application" project. When I created the webservice and global files (using "Add Item" from the right click context menu), the code behinds weren't in App_Code. But the only way to get the files to run on the server was to put them in App_Code...I feel like I'm missing a step somewhere.

Comment: I updated my comment. The step you are missing is creating a deployable compiled version of your web app. Use the publish option in visual studio.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that existed. I usually work on a LAMP stack, so this stuff is pretty new to me. I'll give that a shot and see how that works out. Can you speak to best practices? It seems to me that it would make sense to deploy the code to the server (via git) and then compile the code there instead of keeping the compiled files in source control. Would that be accurate? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would not deploy via git, but you are correct that you don't want to store the compiled files in source control. On windows mysysgit will create a standard .gitignore file that will exclude the compiled binaries. For automated build and deployment check out tools like team city, cruisecontrol.net and octopus deploy. They can check the source code out of git, build and deploy. They can do this on every commit/push, periodically or on demand.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I'll look into these new tools. For what it's worth to anyone else reading this, I added a batch="false" to the compilation line of my web.config which eliminated the need for putting my code behinds in the App_Code directory.